# In the famous speech from the film "Network", he says "Let me have my toaster and my TV and my steel belted radials", what are steel belted radials?

Tags: meaning

> 'Please, at least leave us alone in our living rooms. Let me have my toaster and my TV and my steel-belted radials and I won't say anything. Just leave us alone.'

I looked on google and apparently 'steel belted radials' are a type of tyre. However I thought until I googled it that he was be referring in this speech to an old style radio which have radial dials, which would fit in with him naming three appliances found in the home.

What is he actually referring to? Is it a way to refer to his car, perhaps?

Comment: He's referring to the tire

Comment: 'He' is certainly referring to tyres, but whether he's using this metonymically for his car is unclear (though likely).

Comment: It means "leave me alone with my possessions": note the possessions are all of the "modern convenience" bordering on "luxury" type (for the time). Unnecessary things which are promised, in America's conspicuous consumer culture, to bring comfort, to act as salve to soothe our wounded souls.  An automatic toast-making machine, a boob tube, a set of fancy and expensive tires for my car. Ornaments. Empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker is listing consumer goods that are sold on television morning noon and night. The consumer he describes is begging to be left alone in peace with his collected possessions.

Comment: Notably, "steel-belted radials" were once (in the 70s) the *crème de la crème* of auto tires.  *Network* was released in 1976.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll mark as accepted as although the actual answer itself doesn't directly answer the question, your comment does.